# Laravel installation via composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

When I try and run the following (Mac OS X Yosemite):

```
↦ composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

I get the following error:

```
Changed current directory to /Users/USER/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v1.1.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.1.7, 4.1.8, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3].
    - laravel/installer v1.1.1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.1.7, 4.1.8, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3].
    - laravel/installer v1.1.2 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.1.7, 4.1.8, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3].
    - laravel/installer v1.1.3 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.1.7, 4.1.8, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3].
    - laravel/installer v1.2.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 4.1.5, 4.1.6, 4.1.7, 4.1.8, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3].
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.2.3 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~2.1 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.2.2 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~2.1 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.2.1 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~2.1 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.2.0 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~2.1 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.1.8 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~1.4 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.1.7 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~1.4 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.1.6 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~1.4 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.1.5 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~1.4 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.1.4 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~1.4 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.1.3 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~1.3 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.1.2 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.1.1 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.1.0 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.0.2 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.0.1 requires guzzlehttp/streams ~1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/streams 1.* -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ~1.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.1.3, v1.2.0].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

All I have globally installed is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/lumen-installer": "~1.0"
    }
}
```

I have tried globally requiring guzzlehttp/streams, and also tried requiring the latest version of laravel, but to no help.

My machine is pretty new, and I haven't done anything wrt composer until now.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those that experience this problem see: https://github.com/laravel/lumen-installer/issues/2

Credit to moraleslevi

"For what it's worth, removing the .composer/vendor/guzzlehttp folder and re-installing the laravel installer worked."

Answer (score 0):

try first clear composer cache the use composer run

```
composer clearcache 
composer clear-cache
rm -rf ~/.composer/cache*
```

Comment: Hi user, I have just tried that and it comes up with the same error.